# Is the function id: $(\mathbb{R},T_{st}) \to (\mathbb{R},T_{count})$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Given are two topological spaces $(\mathbb{R},T_{st})$ and $(\mathbb{R},T_{count})$, where $T_{st}$ is the standard/euclidian topology and where $T_{count}$ is the topology with $U\subset{T_{count}}$ open if $\mathbb{R}\backslash{U}$ is countable or if $U = \emptyset$ .

Now consider; id: $(\mathbb{R},T_{st})\to(\mathbb{R},T_{count})$. I need to determine whether the function id is continuous or not with the given mapping. 
I know that id is continuous with the given mapping if for every $U\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ open w.r.t. $T_{count}$ we have that $id^{-1}(U)\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ is open w.r.t. $T_{st}$ as well.

**Q:** Given $U\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ open w.r.t. $T_{count}$ we have that $\mathbb{R}\backslash{U}$ is countable. How do I show that $U\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ is open/closed w.r.t. $T_{st}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ the set of irrational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set of irrationals $\mathbb{Q}^c$, It is open with respect to $T_{count}$ as its complement is the set of rationals which is countable. However it is not open with respect to $T_{st}$.